# Whitelist all EC2 instances from a particular AWS account in another AWS account's security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I currently have a Lambda function that performs a series of task, but one part in particular requires connection to an RDS instance in another AWS account. The function spins up a new EC2 instance at each trigger and uses userdata to perform the series of tasks I have written.

The RDS instance has a security group, and I would need to whitelist the EC2 instance's IP to connect. This is infeasible as I am spinning up a new EC2 instance each time the function is triggered. Is there a way to whitelist all EC2 instance's in a particular AWS account in another AWS account's security group rules?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you dont want your traffic to go over the internet.

[Updating your security groups to reference peer VPC groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html)

> You can update the inbound or outbound rules for your VPC security groups to reference security groups in the peered VPC. Doing so allows traffic to flow to and from instances that are associated with the referenced security group in the peered VPC.

> The peer VPC can be a VPC in your account, or a VPC in another AWS account. To reference a security group in another AWS account, include the account number in Source or Destination field; for example, `123456789012/sg-1a2b3c4d.`

This is the most elegant way instead of whitelisting all ec2 instances. Traffic always stays on the global AWS backbone, and never traverses the public internet, which reduces threats, such as common exploits, and DDoS attacks.

You still hold the controls what can be accessed between the accounts via many methods

- Security groups
- Route Tables
- Network ACLs.